# JavaScript loop over clickable elements on click event, and skip the specific clicked element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<div>
 <div class="clickable">1</div>
 <div class="clickable">2</div>
 <div class="clickable">3</div>
 <div class="clickable">4</div>
</div>
```

Upon clicking one of the 'clickable' elements i want to add a new class to all elements with 'clickable' class **except** the one that has been clicked.

```
 $('.clickable').on('click', function (e) {
            $('.clickable').each(function () {
               $(this).addClass('new-class')

            });
})
```

How, inside the loop, can i skip the specific element that was clicked?

Comment: You can change your loop like this : `$('.clickable').not($(this)).each(function () {`

Comment: Inside the click callback you can refer to the clicked element using `e.currentTarget`
Then you can remove the `new-class` or skip it entirely.

Comment: Or directly use `$('.clickable').not($(this)).addClass('new-class')` .

Comment: @Swati there is no need to include `$(this)` selector when you call not method, you can just directly pass `this` to not method and it will select it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `not` method in `jQuery` so the simplest thing you can do in my opinion is with the help of not method like below:

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function (e) {
  $('.clickable').not(this).addClass('new-class');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest to control and read

You do not need the each

```js
$('.clickable').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.clickable').addClass('new-class');
  $(this).removeClass('new-class'); 
})
```

```css
.new-class {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="clickable">1</div>
  <div class="clickable">2</div>
  <div class="clickable">3</div>
  <div class="clickable">4</div>
</div>
```

If they are surely all in the same container, you can use siblings.
To chain you MUST remove before adding

```js
$('.clickable').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this)
   .removeClass('new-class')  // still necessary for the second click of another element
   .siblings().addClass('new-class');
})
```

```css
.new-class {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="clickable">1</div>
  <div class="clickable">2</div>
  <div class="clickable">3</div>
  <div class="clickable">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('new-class').siblings().addClass('new-class');
});
```